# Find all image in div of another page and insert to this page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to get all the images in a `div` of another page and include them to current page. I tried this code but It's not working.

```
<div id="preview-image"></div>
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: '(my_url)',
    success: function(data) {
        $(".message img", data).each(function() {
            $(this).appendTo('#preview-image');
        });
    }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Define "not working". Is `success` being called at all? What does `data` contain, if so? Any errors in the [JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Comment: I think you shouldn't include the url into parentheses

Comment: there's no error in Javascript console.

Comment: @IlyaKushlianski actually I don't use parentheses in my code.

Comment: Is the script you're sending to not working? You need to drill down a little more and figure out which part isn't working. There are multiple points of failure here.

Comment: Maybe it's worth checking the context of $(this)

Comment: @IlyaKushlianski No, `this` will be each matching `<img>` found, in turn (if any -- we still don't know what `data` contains).

Comment: I want get all the images contain in `<div class="message">...</div>` in that page, then attach all into `#preview-image`. If my code isn't right so can anyone give me a correctly code?